# NgRx live example fails with error message "Property 'store' is used before its initialization

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm just getting started with NgRx and I'm struggling with the live example in the Walkthrough of NgRx (https://ngrx.io/guide/store/walkthrough). It fails with the following error message:

Property 'store' is used before its initialization.

Does anyone know how to fix it? I have created a StackBlitz fork here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wstvmm?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: if you initialize `books$` and `bookCollection$` in `ngOnInit` it fixes the issue. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wstvmm-3dxj4w

Comment: you can also do the initialization  in the constructor to get the same effect you you are attempting to do.

Comment: Thanks guys, that was it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
  books$;
  bookCollection$;
  
  constructor(private booksService: GoogleBooksService, private store: Store) {
    this.books$ = this.store.select(selectBooks);
    this.bookCollection$ = this.store.select(selectBookCollection);
  }
```